# Scaling 3D models, finding the origin

Tags: algorithm, matrix, 3d, scaling

To get a better idea of how matrix transformations work cause I'm having a fairly hard time seeing what actually happens, I decided to write some scripts that will take a 3D model and then do some translations, rotations, and scaling, since looking at what actually happens when I play around with different values may be helpful.

I've already written the scripts to parse a 3D model, so now I just need to write the transformation functions.

I am using the Euclid module, which was amongst several suggestions for working with matrices (though this question is not really python-specific so I left out that tag)

So far I've been able to successfully translate a model based on the x,y,z values that I provide.

Now I'm working on the scaling function, and have also managed to scale the model by whatever factor, but I'm having a hard time getting it to scale "on the spot" since the model isn't centered at the origin.

How can I build a transform matrix that will take into account the center of some arbitrary model?

Comment: do you have a clear definition of 'the center'?

Comment: @Randy, no, but someone told me to find the maximum and minimum x,y,z values in the model and then take the average of each component and that is "the center"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may scale "around" a point `P` by the following transformation:

```
translate(scale(translate(model, -P)), P)
```

i.e. for a vertex `X` you have

```
X' = P + s * (X-P) = s*X + (P-s*P)
```